# How to get full tool in toolbar option in trading-vue-js

Tags: vue.js, charts, nuxt.js, trading, cryptocurrency

I have build a chart for cryptocurrencies in my NuxtJS project and I added DataCube to my data but I only have LineTool and RangeTool how can i make my toolbar just like tradingview chart ?

Comment: No idea. Could you please make an effort and give us more context on what you've tried so far. A Github link or a [repro] for example.

Answer (score 0):

trading-vue-js only has a limited number of tools in the tool bar. By default it only displays `cursor, line, range`. If you mouse over the line or range tool icons, click on the small arrow to the right `>`, this will reveal a few more tools in that group.

Other than that, there are no more tools. If you want any of the extra tools that tradingview has, they have to be written by yourself or another.